Qtile-extras decorations don't show up
I've recently installed Arch Linux with the Qtile window manager. These days I have been testing and trying to configure Qtile and personalize it. Now I'm trying to add the Qtile-extra's decorations, but they just don't show up. I don't know if I messed up in my config file. Help is appreciated.
Here's my config.py file: https://pastebin.com/wqMgLmd9
# Copyright (c) 2010 Aldo Cortesi
# Copyright (c) 2010, 2014 dequis
# Copyright (c) 2012 Randall Ma
# Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Tycho Andersen
# Copyright (c) 2012 Craig Barnes
# Copyright (c) 2013 horsik
# Copyright (c) 2013 Tao Sauvage
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.

from libqtile import bar, layout, qtile, widget, extension, hook
from libqtile.config import Click, Drag, Group, Key, Match, Screen
from libqtile.lazy import lazy
from libqtile.utils import guess_terminal, send_notification
from qtile_extras.widget import CPUGraph, ContinuousPoll
from qtile_extras.widget.decorations import PowerLineDecoration, RectDecoration

mod = "mod4"
terminal = guess_terminal()

@hook.subscribe.client_killed
def client_killed(client):
    send_notification("qtile", f"{client.name} has been killed.")

@hook.subscribe.client_new
def client_new(client):
    send_notification("qtile", f"{client.name} has been created.")

keys = [
    # A list of available commands that can be bound to keys can be found
    # at https://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/config/lazy.html
    # Switch between windows
    Key([mod], "j", lazy.layout.left(), desc="Move focus to left"),
    Key([mod], "l", lazy.layout.right(), desc="Move focus to right"),
    Key([mod], "k", lazy.layout.down(), desc="Move focus down"),
    Key([mod], "i", lazy.layout.up(), desc="Move focus up"),
    Key([mod], "space", lazy.layout.next(), desc="Move window focus to other window"),
    # Move windows between left/right columns or move up/down in current stack.
    # Moving out of range in Columns layout will create new column.
    Key([mod, "shift"], "j", lazy.layout.shuffle_left(), desc="Move window to the left"),
    Key([mod, "shift"], "l", lazy.layout.shuffle_right(), desc="Move window to the right"),
    Key([mod, "shift"], "k", lazy.layout.shuffle_down(), desc="Move window down"),
    Key([mod, "shift"], "i", lazy.layout.shuffle_up(), desc="Move window up"),
    # Grow windows. If current window is on the edge of screen and direction
    # will be to screen edge - window would shrink.
    Key([mod, "control"], "j", lazy.layout.grow_left(), desc="Grow window to the left"),
    Key([mod, "control"], "l", lazy.layout.grow_right(), desc="Grow window to the right"),
    Key([mod, "control"], "k", lazy.layout.grow_down(), desc="Grow window down"),
    Key([mod, "control"], "i", lazy.layout.grow_up(), desc="Grow window up"),
    Key([mod], "n", lazy.layout.normalize(), desc="Reset all window sizes"),
    # Toggle between split and unsplit sides of stack.
    # Split = all windows displayed
    # Unsplit = 1 window displayed, like Max layout, but still with
    # multiple stack panes
    Key(
        [mod, "shift"],
        "Return",
        lazy.layout.toggle_split(),
        desc="Toggle between split and unsplit sides of stack",
    ),
    Key([mod], "Return", lazy.spawn(terminal), desc="Launch terminal"),
    # Toggle between different layouts as defined below
    Key([mod], "Tab", lazy.next_layout(), desc="Toggle between layouts"),
    Key([mod], "w", lazy.window.kill(), desc="Kill focused window"),
    Key([mod], "f", lazy.window.toggle_fullscreen(), desc="Toggle fullscreen on the focused window"),
    Key([mod], "t", lazy.window.toggle_floating(), desc="Toggle floating on the focused window"),
    Key([mod, "control"], "r", lazy.reload_config(), desc="Reload the config"),
    Key([mod, "control"], "q", lazy.shutdown(), desc="Shutdown Qtile"),
    Key([mod], "r", lazy.run_extension(extension.DmenuRun()), desc="Spawn a command using a prompt widget"),
    Key([mod], "F3", lazy.spawn("sudo /home/b3ctor/brightness_up.sh")),
    Key([mod], "F2", lazy.spawn("sudo /home/b3ctor/brightness_down.sh")),
    Key([mod], "F9", lazy.spawn("amixer sset Master 2-")),
    Key([mod], "F10", lazy.spawn("amixer sset Master 2+")),
    Key([mod],"F11", lazy.spawn("sudo python3 /home/b3ctor/audio_mute.py"))
]

groups = [
    Group("DEV"),
    Group("TERM"),
    Group("NET", matches=[Match(wm_class="Firefox")]),
    Group("FILE"),
    Group("ETC")
]

k=0
for i in groups:
    keys.append(
        Key([mod], f"{k+1}", lazy.group[groups[k].name].toscreen()),
    )
    k+=1

# Add key bindings to switch VTs in Wayland.
# We can't check qtile.core.name in default config as it is loaded before qtile is started
# We therefore defer the check until the key binding is run by using .when(func=...)
for vt in range(1, 8):
    keys.append(
        Key(
            ["control", "mod1"],
            f"f{vt}",
            lazy.core.change_vt(vt).when(func=lambda: qtile.core.name == "wayland"),
            desc=f"Switch to VT{vt}",
        )
    )


# groups = [Group(i) for i in "123456789"]

# for i in groups:
#     keys.extend(
#         [
#             # mod + group number = switch to group
#             Key(
#                 [mod],
#                 i.name,
#                 lazy.group[i.name].toscreen(),
#                 desc="Switch to group {}".format(i.name),
#             ),
#             # mod + shift + group number = switch to & move focused window to group
#             Key(
#                 [mod, "shift"],
#                 i.name,
#                 lazy.window.togroup(i.name, switch_group=False),
#                 desc="Switch to & move focused window to group {}".format(i.name),
#             ),
#             # Or, use below if you prefer not to switch to that group.
#             # # mod + shift + group number = move focused window to group
#             # Key([mod, "shift"], i.name, lazy.window.togroup(i.name),
#             #     desc="move focused window to group {}".format(i.name)),
#         ]
#     )

layout_theme = {
    "border_width": 3,
    "margin": 15,
    "border_focus": "FFFFFF",
    "border_normal": "CCCCCC"
}

layouts = [
    layout.Columns(**layout_theme),
    layout.Max(),
    # Try more layouts by unleashing below layouts.
    # layout.Stack(num_stacks=2),
    # layout.Bsp(),
    layout.Matrix(),
    # layout.MonadTall(),
    # layout.MonadWide(),
    # layout.RatioTile(),
    # layout.Tile(),
    # layout.TreeTab(),
    # layout.VerticalTile(),
    # layout.Zoomy(),
]

widget_defaults = dict(
    font="Caskaydia Mono",
    fontsize=12,
    padding=5,
)
extension_defaults = widget_defaults.copy()

powerline = {
    "decorations": [
        RectDecoration(use_widget_background=True, padding_y=5, filled=True, radius=0),
        PowerLineDecoration(path="arrow_right", padding_y=5)
    ]
}

screens = [
    Screen(
        top=bar.Bar(
            [
                ALSAWidget(
                    mode='both',
                    theme_path='/home/b3ctor/.config/qtile/audio.png',
                    padding=5,
                    icon_size=5

                ),
                widget.QuickExit(
                    default_text="⏻",
                    padding = 50,
                    background = "#f72020",
                ),
                widget.GroupBox(
                    highlight_method='line',
                    borderwidth = 2,
                    disable_drag = True,
                    highlight_color = "#ff4b2b",
                    padding = 6,
                    active = "#ffffff",
                    inactive = "#ffffff",
                ),
                widget.WindowName(**powerline),
                widget.Volume(background='444444', **powerline),
                widget.Chord(
                    chords_colors={
                        "launch": ("#ff0000", "#ffffff"),
                    },
                    name_transform=lambda name: name.upper(),
                ),
                # NB Systray is incompatible with Wayland, consider using StatusNotifier instead
                widget.CPUGraph(background='444444', **powerline),
                widget.Notify(
                    audiofile="",
                    background="#edab40",
                    mouse_callbacks={
                        "test":lazy.spawn(terminal)
                    }, **powerline
                ),
                widget.Clock(format="%d-%m-%Y %a %I:%M %p"),
            ],
            30,
            background = "#bf3621",
            margin = 5
            # border_width=[2, 0, 2, 0],  # Draw top and bottom borders
            # border_color=["ff00ff", "000000", "ff00ff", "000000"]  # Borders are magenta
        ),
        # You can uncomment this variable if you see that on X11 floating resize/moving is laggy
        # By default we handle these events delayed to already improve performance, however your system might still be struggling
        # This variable is set to None (no cap) by default, but you can set it to 60 to indicate that you limit it to 60 events per second
        # x11_drag_polling_rate = 60,
    ),
]

# Drag floating layouts.
mouse = [
    Drag([mod], "Button1", lazy.window.set_position_floating(), start=lazy.window.get_position()),
    Drag([mod], "Button3", lazy.window.set_size_floating(), start=lazy.window.get_size()),
    Click([mod], "Button2", lazy.window.bring_to_front()),
]

dgroups_key_binder = None
dgroups_app_rules = []  # type: list
follow_mouse_focus = True
bring_front_click = False
floats_kept_above = True
cursor_warp = False
floating_layout = layout.Floating(
    float_rules=[
        # Run the utility of `xprop` to see the wm class and name of an X client.
        *layout.Floating.default_float_rules,
        Match(wm_class="confirmreset"),  # gitk
        Match(wm_class="makebranch"),  # gitk
        Match(wm_class="maketag"),  # gitk
        Match(wm_class="ssh-askpass"),  # ssh-askpass
        Match(title="branchdialog"),  # gitk
        Match(title="pinentry"),  # GPG key password entry
    ]
)
auto_fullscreen = True
focus_on_window_activation = "smart"
reconfigure_screens = True

# If things like steam games want to auto-minimize themselves when losing
# focus, should we respect this or not?
auto_minimize = True

# When using the Wayland backend, this can be used to configure input devices.
wl_input_rules = None

# xcursor theme (string or None) and size (integer) for Wayland backend
wl_xcursor_theme = None
wl_xcursor_size = 24

# XXX: Gasp! We're lying here. In fact, nobody really uses or cares about this
# string besides java UI toolkits; you can see several discussions on the
# mailing lists, GitHub issues, and other WM documentation that suggest setting
# this string if your java app doesn't work correctly. We may as well just lie
# and say that we're a working one by default.
#
# We choose LG3D to maximize irony: it is a 3D non-reparenting WM written in
# java that happens to be on java's whitelist.
wmname = "LG3D"

This is how my Qtile is looking at the moment. I know it's not beautiful. I'm relatively new to Linux.

